# Save image to app in WinRT and C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to create a game where the user have the opportunity to load his own graphics and now I have to save these images in my app, how can I do this? Because the user can delete the images from the HDD, but I want to have the images nevertheless in my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When the user loads the graphics from, say, this Pictures folders, you could copy the file to the application's [Local Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx).  It's still resident on the machine but somewhat obscured in the `%AppData%\Local\Packages` folder.

Of course, that doesn't guarantee the file won't be deleted by a savvy user, and it doubles the amount of storage that's strictly necessary for your app, since the user might not have deleted the original files.

Another option is to do your own backup of the images to cloud storage, say Windows Azure blob storage, whenever the user loads his own graphics.  You'd then be sure to have everything available to you, but it's in the cloud, so you add an additional moving part to your solution, and you'll need to deal with disconnected scenarios, latency, etc.